# How to call object method in javasctipt?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to call this method named 'prototype' but I don't know how to call it.(last method)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWODu.png)

how should I call this method?

I tried .[[Prototype]] .Prototype .prototype and ...

Comment: The only method in this picture is `tooltipMoveEvent`. Nothing about `prototype` or [[Prototype]] is a method. See [How to access object prototype in javascript?](/q/7662147/4642212). What specifically do you need? Also, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212).

Comment: *"I want to call this method named 'prototype'"* - What do you think this "method" does...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Prototype property like so:

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(myObject)
```

Make sure myObject is defined before you call this.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes for more information.

If you are not expecting the Prototype property in this object, please describe what your code is doing and provide snippets related to the bug.